# How to reduce the size of vendor.js in an NUXT + EXPRESS based project?

Tags: express, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am setting up a website and come cross the problem that the size of vendor.js is  as big as up to 700KB.

I start running the project on server with the CMD "cross-env NODE_ENV=production nodemon server/index.j".

```
// server/index.js
const nuxt = new Nuxt(config);
app.use(nuxt.render)
```

Now i am trying to compress the javascript files by turning on gzip mode in nginx.
Although it works and makes the page load much quicker, i am still wondering if there is another way or webpack plugin to approach this like uglifyJS.

Comment: You can use [vue-cli-plugin-webpack-bundle-analyzer](https://github.com/mrbbot/vue-cli-plugin-webpack-bundle-analyzer) or [webpack-bundle-analyzer](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-bundle-analyzer)

Answer (score 1):

Nuxt do minify and uglify js files by default for production builds. See [docs here](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build#optimization)

Nuxt also have a build in webpack analyze. [Docs](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build#analyze) You can check what js take most space and try to optimize it via treeshaking or replacing with other lib :)

Also dont use components globally, only use where u need them, that will help too.